# Get most recent result for each item in a list?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table structure with fake data like so:

```
id | time_created | result_data
---+--------------+-------------   
A  | 3/1/2020     | 123
A  | 4/10/2020    | 456
B  | 5/3/2020     | 789
B  | 2/5/2020     | 101
```

I can't figure out how to

1. get all unique ID's and then
2. get the most recent (i.e., top 1 most recent) `result_data` for that entry.

In order words, using the example data, I'd like to get the most recent version of A (the 4/10/2020 data) and the most recent version of B (5/3/2020 version) i.e. rows 2 and 3.

This query assumes I don't know the unique ID's in advance, so I'll have to have something like `WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM mytable)` But how would you actually make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with window function `row_number`.

```
select
    id,
    time_created,
    result_date
from
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by time_created desc) as rn
    from yourTable
) val
where rn = 1
```

Your inner query produce following result using [row_number](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/)

```
id | time_created | result_data| rn
---+--------------+------------|---   
A  | 4/10/2020    | 456        | 1  
A  | 3/1/2020     | 123        | 2
B  | 2/5/2020     | 101        | 1
B  | 5/3/2020     | 789        | 2
```

and in your outer query you are selecting only most recent records by selecting `rn =1`

Comment: Wow, nice, this worked. Is there any easy way to understand what the code is doing here? I'd love to understand it a tiny bit more.

Comment: @yoursweater I have provided an explanation and link for `row_number` documentation. you can look at other window functions as well.

Answer (score 2):

use corelated subquery

```
select *
from table a
where time_created = (
    select max(time_created)
    from table b
    where a.id = b.id
)
```

or using `row_number()`

```
select b.*
from (
    select a.*
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by time_created desc) rn
    from table a
) b
where b.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(TIME_CREATED) TIME_CREATED
    FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT A.ID, A.TIME_CREATED, A.RESULT_DATA
FROM MYTABLE A
INNER JOIN CTE ON A.ID = CTE.ID AND A.TIME_CREATED = CTE.TIME_CREATED
```